# Android studio referring to build.gradle from incorrect project

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have three android studio projects:

- (path)\LibAddressLookup
- (path)\App_A
- (path)\App_B

Both App_A and App_B rely on LibAddressLookup and have references to it in their settings/gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':LibAddressLookup'
project(':LibAddressLookup').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../LibAddressLookup/app')
```

App_A has about 14 different build flavours, App_B has just the one

When attempting to load App_B into Android Studio, gradle build fails. Looking at my "Build Variants" window, I see that the module "app" has the flavours/build config combinations for App_A. When I go to edit flavours, I see ll the flavours from App_A listed. If I attempt to edit (remove) the flavours I am greeted with an error message saying that the build.grade does not belong to the project, and then lists the location of App_A's build.grade, as pictured:

[image: build.gradle does not belong to project]

In the 'Android' view of Android Studio, I see that there are two build.gradle's showing as belonging to "Module" App", as pictured:

[image: unwanted build.gradle]

When looking at the files, one is indeed the one from App_A, while the other one is the correct one from App_B. I can't find any way to remove this file from the project. Creating fresh copies of the project in new directories leads to the same problem repeating itself. How do I get rid of the incorrect build.grade, and allow myself to continue working on App_B???

Comment: I think you are using same package name in both library and project.

Comment: nope, all three projects have different package names. Even if it were the case, how does Android Studio even KNOW about App_A when loading App_B from a different directory. Even if the package name was the same, it still should work.

Comment: well in some cases android really drive you mad. I had the same issue when I converted a project to a library and used that in another project. Turns out when you create a new project android creates an app folder by default. Now if you add another one it will go by the same name and thus 2 apps will be there to run. I deleted that folder along with all default activities and it worked in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution, but I'm leaving the question open for a while in case anybody can enlighten me as to how this may have happened, so I can prevent it happening again.

In the file (path)\App_B.idea\workspace.xml was the following entry:

```
<component name="ExternalProjectsData">
    <projectState path="$PROJECT_DIR$/../App_A">
      <ProjectState />
    </projectState>
    <projectState path="$PROJECT_DIR$">
      <ProjectState />
    </projectState>
</component>
```

After removing the first projectState sub-entry (referring to App_A),  reopening Android Studio, cleaning the project, exiting again, restarting, and cleaning again, Android Studio was finally ready to accept that App_A really did have nothing to do with App_B.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It only works at the first time but my AS still auto add "App_A" to "App_B" project after I open "App_A" project and then open "App_B" project. Do you have the same issue? How do you fix it?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77944645 should be the same issue as this one.